# Ubuntu22.04 - fail to run script using systemd

Tags: systemd

I need to run a script at every boot. For that, I've create a `.sh` file, which runs as needed using a terminal.

To make it run during boot, I followed [this](https://www.shubhamdipt.com/blog/how-to-create-a-systemd-service-in-linux/) tutorial.

`.sh` file:

```
#! /bin/bash

sub1="myHome/Messages"
sub2="myHome/log"
sub3="myHome/debug"
user="guy"
pass="kupelu9e"
mqtt_broker="192.168.2.100"

gnome-terminal --tab --title $sub1 -- mosquitto_sub -u $user -P $pass -h $mqtt_broker -t $sub1
gnome-terminal --tab --title $sub2 -- mosquitto_sub -u $user -P $pass -h $mqtt_broker -t $sub2
gnome-terminal --tab --title $sub3 -- mosquitto_sub -u $user -P $pass -h $mqtt_broker -t $sub3

gnome-terminal -- mosquitto_pub -u $user  -P $pass -h $mqtt_broker -t "myHome/All" -m "status"
```

Unit file

```
[Unit]
Description=Runs terminalwith MQTT subs
After=network.target auditd.service

[Service]
User=guy
WorkingDirectory=/home/guy
ExecStart=/bin/bash 123.sh
```

running the deamon yeild an error:

```
guy@desktop:~$ systemctl status mqtt_subs.service 
× mqtt_subs.service - Runs terminalwith MQTT subs
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mqtt_subs.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2023-04-11 15:12:53 IDT; 10s ago
    Process: 5193 ExecStart=/bin/bash mqtts.sh (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 5193 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 273ms

Apr 11 15:12:52 desktop systemd[1]: Started Runs terminalwith MQTT subs.
Apr 11 15:12:52 desktop bash[5195]: # Failed to parse arguments: Cannot open display:
Apr 11 15:12:53 desktop bash[5197]: # Failed to parse arguments: Cannot open display:
Apr 11 15:12:53 desktop bash[5199]: # Failed to parse arguments: Cannot open display:
Apr 11 15:12:53 desktop bash[5201]: # Failed to parse arguments: Cannot open display:
Apr 11 15:12:53 desktop systemd[1]: mqtt_subs.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 11 15:12:53 desktop systemd[1]: mqtt_subs.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
guy@desktop:~$
```

To be sure that the `systemd` service runs and defined  OK - I modified `123.sh` into an echo to write into a file (meaning - a very simple task), I don't get any error.

Appreciate any help

Guy

Comment: You run a command (`gnome-terminal`) that needs a graphic environment, at boot. The graphic environment may not have been started at that point, so you want to make the service dependent on that target. Second, you will need to provide a DISPLAY parameter, which is usually `:0` on a single-user system.

Comment: Can you write the correct syntax for first part ?

Comment: I believe `Requires=graphical.target` in the `[Unit]` section should work.

Comment: I think this has to be a user systemd.service.  I was using the https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Systemd/User

Comment: @nobody can you explain more ?